# dotless engine parser returns empty string

Tags: css, parsing, asp.net-mvc-4, less, bundling-and-minification

ASP.Net MVC4 + Bootstrap (LESS) + dotLess.

Goal is to transform the Bootstrap `.less` files into a single bundle of `.css`, and I'm running into showstopper issues.

#### Bundle.config

```
var bootstrapStyles = new Bundle("~/bundle/style/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/less/*.less");
bootstrapStyles.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
bootstrapStyles.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(bootstrapStyles);
```

Only bootstrap's less files, which should not have any red-flag syntax problems.

The next step was to build that transformer class `LessTransform` to produce the css.

The transformer class implements the `Process()` and the problematic code exists inside... here's both scenarios and their problems:

#### Scenario 1: Static `Less.Parse()`

```
var parsedLess = Less.Parse(bundle.Content);
bundle.Content = parsedLess;

// Throws a FileNotFoundException
// "You are importing a file ending in .less that cannot be found."
// reset.less and it definitely exists in that folder.
```

#### Scenario 2: LessEngine.TransformToCss()

```
var content = new StringBuilder();
var engine = new LessEngine();

foreach (var file in bundle.Files)
{
    // text is extracted correctly.
    var text = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
    // transform function returns an empty string, no errors
    var css = engine.TransformToCss(text, file.FullName);
    content.AppendLine(css);
}
bundle.Content = content.ToString();
```

#### Question

Anyone have an insight on either of these errors? Know any solutions? Neither make sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: If you use `LessWeb.Parse(content, DotlessConfiguration.GetDefaultWeb());` instead of `Less.Parse(content);` you'll get a better error message. At least that's what I got.

Comment: I'll check that out. Oddly enough they suggest the Parser... thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow! That's a lot of hoop jumping to find the source of the problem.

A good strategy for such problems is to peel away the layers to the simplest case.  You're not seeing any error messages because something in the bundling process is eating up dotless's logging messages, which should be dealt with separately.  This assumes you have dotless error logging turned on.

Instead, of using:

@Styles.Render("~/bundle/style/bootstrap")

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="~/Content/style/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" />
```

When you try to view the less file in the browser, you should get the following message:

> directive block with unrecognised format on line 253 in file
>   '/Content/Themes/bootstrap/mixins.less':
>
> [252]:   // Multiple shadow solution from
>   http://toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/
>   [253]:   @props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
>          --^ [254]:   -webkit-box-shadow: @props;

The source of this problem is attributed to a hack in bootstrap that doesn't play well with dotless.  To fix this problem, replace the following lines in mixins.less:

```
// Drop shadows
.box-shadow(@shadowA, @shadowB:X, ...){
  // Multiple shadow solution from http://toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/
  @props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
  -webkit-box-shadow: @props;
     -moz-box-shadow: @props;
          box-shadow: @props;
}
```

with the following lines:

```
// Drop shadows
.box-shadow(@shadow){
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
     -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
          box-shadow: @shadow;
}
.box-shadow(@shadow1, @shadow2) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2;
     -moz-box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2;
          box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2;
}
.box-shadow(@shadow1, @shadow2, @shadow3) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2, @shadow3;
     -moz-box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2, @shadow3;
          box-shadow: @shadow1, @shadow2, @shadow3;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5079 - should not be a problem from 2.1.2 on.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1 (Solved)**

It turns out, it was not actually failing on 'reset.less' but on 'bootstrap.less' who's first line is an import statement to 'reset.less'. Implementing a path resolver in the loop fixed that issue.

```
// let them throw exceptions on casting because they should never be null.
var importer = (Importer)lessParser.Importer;
var filereader = (FileReader)importer.FileReader;
// "As" casting here ensures if the path resolver is another type that we cannot cast 
// (ex. RelativePathResolver) that we get a null rather than an exception.
var pathresolver = filereader.PathResolver as ImportedFilePathResolver;
if (pathresolver != null)
    pathresolver.CurrentFilePath = currentFilePath;
else
    filereader.PathResolver = new ImportedFilePathResolver(currentFilePath);
```

**Scenario 2 (Still Broken)**

See Joel's answer above. It is correct. One thing to note, this Tony Stark hack will be removed from Bootstrap 2.1.2, just around the corner: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5079

Comment: Have you figured out why dotless isn't outputting syntax errors?  It makes it a pain to debug track down why you're stylesheet is failing.